# Somatosensory System

Tags: neuroscience

I have a test in my upcoming Neuroscience class, one of the items on the study guide is:

Identify 2 means by which a maintained, constant stimulus produces only a transient excitation of the Pacinian corpuscle (phasic receptor). How does adaptation occur?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider physical filtering properties of the corpuscle sheath as well as adaptation of the neuron or downstream targets.